# Enviar a una copia al remitente formulario PHP

Tags: php, formularios

¿cómo puedo mandar una copia del formulario al remitente cuya dirección de correo es $email?

Comment: Creo que esto te servirá. $mail->AddCC($email); [Enlace Original.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25153870/add-cc-in-php-mailer-not-working)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

En ese caso sería:

`$mail->AddCC($email);`

Puedes obtener más información aquí:

https://phpmailer.github.io/PHPMailer/classes/PHPMailer.PHPMailer.PHPMailer.html#method_addCC

Comment: podria agregar una descripcion del porque utilizastes esta funccion o un ejemplo basico, sino sera puesta como publicacion de baja calidad!